# ReactJS: How to get the data of a table row that has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main Table component that maintains the table's state. I have a dumb component which gets props from the main component. I use it to render the table row layout. I am trying to make this table editable. For this reason, I need a way to find out which `tr` was edited. Is there a way to get access to the tr `key` using which I can get access to the whole object?

Comment: Please add some code of what you've done so far.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get the value of a key in a child prop. From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys-must-only-be-unique-among-siblings):

> Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your
>   components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it
>   explicitly as a prop with a different name

```
const content = posts.map((post) =>
  <Post
    key={post.id}
    id={post.id}
    title={post.title} />
);
```

A possible solution right of my head might be the following:

```
import React from 'react';


class Table extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            rows: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    title: "ABC"
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: "DEF"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: "GHI"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <table>
            <tbody>

            {
                this.state.rows.map((item) => <Row key={item.id} item={item} updateItem={this.updateItem} />)
            }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

    updateItem = (newItemData) => {
        const index = this.state.rows.findIndex((r) => r.id == newItemData.id);

        let updatedRows = this.state.rows;

        updatedRows.splice(index, 1, newItemData);

        this.setState({
            rows: updatedRows
        });

    }
}


const Row = ({item, updateItem}) => {

    const [title, setValue] = React.useState(item.title);

    return <tr>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value={title} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)} />
        </td>
        <td>
            <button onClick={() => updateItem({...item, title})}>Save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have this strange problem where the value of index for all the rows is getting set to the key of the last row. Do you know why that could be happening?

Comment: I made some errors in my code (assignment instead of comparison,..). I fixed them and this should solve the issue. Otherwise it's hard to tell. Do you use the code represented or is the issue in your own code?

Comment: well then you might add your code or write another questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send from nested component to parent some data use a callback function